# How to set up AWS region when using older (non builder()) AWS api

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried both `BasicAWSCredential` and `PropertiesCredentials`. They have the same result:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. 
Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
```

Now the complication is - unlike the newer SDK that has the following:

```
 setRegion
```

The older ones do not. I need to *not use the file system* so can not create a credentials file: are there any approaches that are memory only that will work here?